# How to prove that it is a topology

Tags: general-topology

I have the set

$$\Omega_r=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2, x^2+y^2=r^2\}, r\geq0$$

and i consider $\sigma$ the familly of $\emptyset$ and all union of the set $\Omega_r$

How to prove that it is a topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ ?

It is clear that $\emptyset\in \sigma$ and $\mathbb{R}^2=\bigcup_{r\geq0}\Omega_r$

But if i take  $O=\cup_{r\in L}\Omega_r$ and $S=\cup_{s\in S}\Omega_s$ what is $O\cap S$ please ?

Answer (score 2):

It's simply $\bigcup _{r\in L\cap S}\Omega_r$ because the $\Omega_r$ are pairwise disjoint.

In fact, whenever you have a set $X$ and an equivalence relation on $X$, then there is a topology on $X$ where the open sets are precisely the unions  of equivalence classes.

Comment: and the union plese?

Comment: the intersection is $\emptyset$ or $\Omega_r, r=s$? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your open sets are union of circles centered at the origin.

The intersections of such unions are what they have in common which is either empty set or another union of such circles.

Technically, you may write, $$ \bigg( \bigcup _{r\in L}\Omega_r \bigg)\bigcap     \bigg(\bigcup _{r\in  S}\Omega_r\bigg )                  =\bigcup _{r\in L\cap S}\Omega_r$$

Comment: what it means $r\in L\cap S$ ?, please can you give me an example ?@Mohammed

Comment: That means those  radii  which are in both L and S

Comment: and $\bigg( \bigcup _{r\in L}\Omega_r \bigg)\bigcap     \bigg(\bigcup _{s\in  S}\Omega_s\bigg ) =?$ thank you

Comment: Circles whose radii are in both L and S

Comment: and for the union how i do? i say Let $(O_{\lambda})_{\lambda\in \Lambda}\in \sigma$ then $$\bigcup_{\lambda\in \Lambda}(\cup_{r\in L_{\lambda}}\Omega_{r}=\bigcup_{(\lambda,r)\in \Lambda\times L_{\lambda}}\Omega_r$$ how to continue please

Comment: Sound right. You forget to close the parentheses.

Comment: there is nothing to do after ?

Comment: Obviously your set is non-empty, so you are done.